# What is the value and how is the model parameter being used?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Analyzing this code I am not sure what is actually happening.I keep falling into this trap with JS especially with callbacks.  Here is an example taken from backbone's documentation.

```
//creates a new constructor function with a promptColor function as an attribute.    

var Sidebar = Backbone.Model.extend({
  promptColor: function() {
    var cssColor = prompt("Please enter a CSS color:");
    this.set({color: cssColor});
  }
});

// creates a property on the global window object called sidebar  

window.sidebar = new Sidebar;

// .on is an event listener and passed a callback function taking the parameters of model and color.  Here is my confusion, what does it do with the model parameter?

sidebar.on('change:color', function(model, color) {
  $('#sidebar').css({background: color});
});

sidebar.set({color: 'white'});

sidebar.promptColor();
```

My main question is what does it do with the model parameter? What is it actually doing with the model parameter?

Thanks!

Comment: Does nothing, but if it's first it has to be there. If you don't use it you could name it anything, like `_`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your particular case the model parameter is of no real use since their is a 1-to-1 relationship between the change event and the model.

However, there are times when this is not the case.  For example, imagine you have a backbone collection of models.  You can attach a "change" event listener to the collection which will get called every time any model in the collection changes.  In cases like this, it's helpful to know which model originated the "change" event.